# Is this a gas leak from back the back of my oven and is it dangerous?

Tags: leak, gas, oven, gasleak

https://youtu.be/FQXYIAQ7ywA

This is a video of the gas connection on the back of my oven. I covered the connection with soap water. It is bubbling. I do not smell any gas. Is this a problem and is it dangerous?

Comment: Just curious: What is *your own* best explanation for the growing bubbles?

Comment: Out of curiosity: if you didn't smell any gas, why did you check for a gas leak? Is that just a regular thing that you do, or was it a sudden instinct or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is a leak, a slow leak but a leak nonetheless and it does need to be addressed.

Any leak no matter how small is potentially dangerous. You should turn the valve off And address the problem.

Some jurisdictions require that all gas connections be handled by a licensed contractor but if you are allowed then you could turn the gas off, use two adjustable wrenches to disconnect the supply line from the fitting,  clean it up with a brush and apply [pipe dope](http://www.acmehowto.com/plumbing/apply-pipe-dope.php) to the threads and reattach.

Retest with soapy water after you have finished reconnecting.

Comment: Suggest you be sure to get tfe paste which is specifically for gas connections.

Comment: The flexible gas connectors use a flare type fitting that seals by metal-to-metal contact of two beveled surfaces; try tightening it up a bit. Those flex supply lines say right on the label that they are only to be used once, so you may need to replace it. I believe the "one time use" is because repeated flexing can cause them to fatigue and crack rather than having to do with the sealing surface, but they do deform when tightened...

Comment: Flare fittings don't need pipe dope (or teflon paste or tape) to seal properly. All pipe dope might do is lubricate the threads enough to facilitate a slightly tighter fit (which might actually be what you need).